# Como Colocar Dois Like na mesma condição Mysql e PHP

Tags: php, mysql

estou na luta de um sistema em php e mysql sistema de vendas etc..
ele ta tudo funcionando, porém preciso na hora da venda, a pessoa possa pesquisar tanto por (idCodigo ou Descrição). sem ter duas abas de pesquisa. 
queria colocar Dois LIKE para pesquisar por (idCodigo, Descrição) logo ia ter um OR no meio mais não to conseguindo. Segue o Codigo Funcionando com pesquisa apenas com  DESCRICAO

```
public function autoCompleteProdutoSaida($q){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $this->db->like('descricao', $q);  "no caso aqui teria que ter um OR e um LIKE, porém não estou acertando."
    $this->db->where('saida',1);
    $query = $this->db->get('produtos');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = array('label'=>$row['idCodigo']. ' | '.$row['descricao'].' | Preço: R$ '.$row['precoVenda'].' | Estoque: '.$row['estoque'],'estoque'=>$row['estoque'],'id'=>$row['idProdutos'],'preco'=>$row['precoVenda']);
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
}
```

Comment: Acredito que está usando algum framework ou biblioteca, se sim qual?

Comment: estou usando, 
[bcit-ci/CodeIgniter](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter)
* [twbs/bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) 
* [jquery/jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) 
* [jquery/jquery-ui](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Deve estar usando algum framework como visto no seu código.
mais independente de como vai implementar pode fazer alguma analise antes de aplicar a consulta para não impactar no seu sistema.
Exemplo se seu código for apenas numérico, pose fazer uma analise

$this->db->like('descricao', $q);

if(is_numeric) {
   $this->db->like('codigo', $q);
}

Algo assim com isso não vai precisar aplicar uma complexidade para a consulta no banco deixando assim o processo mais rápido.

Comment: tentei, não consegui, a ideia seria o funcionário consegui pesquisar o produto, tanto pelo o código de barras ou pelo o nome do produto. porém só consigo fazer ele pesquisar um ou outro. até então como não conseguir. tive que fazer uma pagina só para consulta, onde ele poderá coloca o nome do produto. e encontrar. e na venda ele usar apenas o código. pois no banco. tem as colunas descricao, idCodigo.

Comment: Uso aqui como te falei em alguns casos, outra ideia é concatenar uma coluna com as informações e fazer a busca por ela usando like. concat(codigo,' ',descricao) descricao, apenas um ideia